# Java graph library for drawing Probability Tree Diagrams

Tags: java, graph, diagram

Is there any Java library that allows me to draw the following diagrams? [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) does not include these kind of diagrams unfortunately.

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try [jgraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) or just create a [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) file and render it separately or use a [Java graphviz API](http://www.loria.fr/~szathmar/off/projects/java/GraphVizAPI/index.php).